# Use result of one SELECT as input to second SELECT and then COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say you have a schema where you're associating employees with thing1 in a table and then thing1 is associated with thing2 in a different table. I want a single query that returns a count of thing2s associated with an employee (by virtue of being associated to a thing1 that's associated to an employee).

Tables:

employee_thing1 (contains employeeID and thing1ID)

thing1_thing2 (contains thing1ID and thing2ID)

Here's my stab at it:

```
 SELECT thing1ID as 'thing1Result' from employee_thing1 where employeeID=?,
 (SELECT 'total' as Name, COUNT(id) from thing1_thing2 as Count where thing1ID=thing1Result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use subquery for getting 'thing1Result'?

```
SELECT 'total' as Name, COUNT(thing2ID) as Count from thing1_thing2 where thing1ID 
in (SELECT thing1ID  from employee_thing1 where employeeID=?)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick stab but perhaps something like this;

```
SET @thing1Result := (SELECT thing1ID FROM employee_thing1 WHERE employeeID=?);
SET @total := (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM thing_thing2 WHERE thing1ID=@thing1result);
```

Give that a try maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` on `LEFT OUTER JOIN` tables for something like this, which counts distinct values not including `NULL` values:

```
SELECT
    employee.employeeID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT employee_thing1.thing1ID) AS 'thing1Count',
    COUNT(DISTINCT thing1_thing2.thing2ID) AS 'thing2Count'
FROM employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_thing1
    ON employee_thing1.employeeID = employee.employeeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN thing1_thing2
    ON thing1_thing2.thing1ID = employee_thing1.thing1ID
WHERE employee.employeeID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Running an inner join on the 3 tables should give you what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'count' FROM `thing1_thing2` 
INNER JOIN `employee_thing1` ON `thing1_thing2`.`thing1ID` = `employee_thing1`.`thing1ID`
INNER JOIN `employees` ON `employee_thing1`.`emplyeeID` = `employees`.`emplyeeID`;
```